# Exceptions when placing a beans.xml file into the META-INF dir

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-3

I am having a maven driven application, which runs beans in glassfish.
Now I want to inject my beans, and therefore I need a beans.xml in place.
But the moment I put it into my META-INF dir, I am getting errors on deploy:

```
Apr 27, 2014 10:05:56 AM org.glassfish.apf.impl.DefaultErrorHandler error
Schwerwiegend: Class [ org/hibernate/Session ] not found. Error while loading [ class dst.ass2.ejb.session.TaskManagementBean ]
Apr 27, 2014 10:05:56 AM com.sun.enterprise.connectors.util.ResourcesUtil getRANameofJdbcConnectionPool
Warnung: RAR8068: Using default datasource : __ds_jdbc_ra for pool : dst-ds-pool
Apr 27, 2014 10:05:57 AM com.sun.enterprise.connectors.util.ResourcesUtil getRANameofJdbcConnectionPool
Warnung: RAR8068: Using default datasource : __ds_jdbc_ra for pool : dst-ds-pool
Apr 27, 2014 10:05:57 AM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
Schwerwiegend: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
Apr 27, 2014 10:05:57 AM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
Schwerwiegend: Exception while preparing the app
Apr 27, 2014 10:05:57 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle deploy
Schwerwiegend: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.maven.PluginUtil.doDeploy(PluginUtil.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.maven.AbstractDeployMojo.doDeploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:239)
    at org.glassfish.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:174)
    ... 45 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seams you need  `spring-orm` dependency

**<dependency><groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>**

Answer (score 0):

I did a `mvn clean`, now this error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at spring-orm maven dependency you will see that it depends on hibernate-entitymanager which is the jar that contains the class not found.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.1.1.RELEASE

Add those dependencies to your maven configuration file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```